# How to fix: sqlite3.ProgrammingError: parameters are of unsupported type?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, pycord, sqlite3-python

I am trying to create a ticket system, where it pulls the guild_id from SQlite3, but it does not work

I have already tried changing it so that its is defined as different things, but it does not work. this is the code

```
conn1 = sqlite3.connect('user.sqlite')
cur1 = conn1.cursor()
conn2 = sqlite3.connect('setup.sqlite')
cur2 = conn2.cursor()
cur1.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ticket 
           (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, discord_name TEXT, discord_id INTEGER, ticket_created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)""")
conn1.commit()
guild = discord.Guild
print(guild)
GUILD_ID = cur2.execute("SELECT guild_id FROM setup WHERE guild_id = ?", (guild.id))
```

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE "setup" (
    "guild_id"  NUMERIC,
    "ticket_channel_id" NUMERIC,
    "category_id_1" NUMERIC,
    "category_id_2" NUMERIC,
    "team_role_id_1"    NUMERIC,
    "team_role_id_2"    NUMERIC,
    "log_channel_id"    NUMERIC,
    "timezone"  TEXT
);
```

Error:

````
parameters are of unsupported type
  File "C:\Users\My name\Documents\Bot\ticket_system.py", line 23, in <module>
    GUILD_ID = cur2.execute("SELECT guild_id FROM setup WHERE guild_id = ?", (guild.id))
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\My name\Documents\Bot\Bot.py", line 20, in <module>
    from ticket_system import Ticket_System
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: parameters are of unsupported type```
````

Comment: Don't make us guess where the error happens.  Please edit the question and post the full error traceback message.

Comment: Also, you're selecting from the `setup` table, but you did not show that table definition.

Comment: `(guild.id)` is `guild.id`, not the single-element tuple `(guild.id,)`, if that’s what you intended.

Comment: @JohnGordon is that what you needed? And I thought I had the error in there.

Comment: @Ry-, even with it at ```(guild.id,)``` It just produces a different error. That being: ```Error binding parameter 1: type 'member_descriptor' is not supported
  File "C:\Users\My name\Documents\Bot\ticket_system.py", line 23, in <module>
    GUILD_ID = cur2.execute("SELECT guild_id FROM setup WHERE guild_id = ?", (guild.id,))
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Error binding parameter 1: type 'member_descriptor' is not supported```

Comment: It looks like `guild.id` is not a numeric type, therefore the database doesn't know how to include it in the query.

Comment: You're using the id from the `discord.Guild` generic class, which I don't think is correct.  You need to use an actual specific guild.

Comment: @JohnGordon I figured, but I can't classify a single guild, other wise it will only look for that guild Id I think. I will try it once I get a chance. But the code is so it can be used in multiple servers, so I need it to be able to pull every guild ID, not just the one I assign in the code.

Comment: Well, that's the point of variables.  They can have different values each time you run the code.  I don't understand why you say "it will only look for that guild id."  If you use a variable, it can be any value you want.

Comment: @JohnGordon I tried defining the id, and i just get the error ```sqlite3.ProgrammingError: Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 1, and there are 19 supplied.```
This is my new code: ```guild = discord.Guild.id = "1156688745253306490"
GUILD_ID  = cur2.execute("SELECT guild_id FROM setup WHERE guild_id = ?", (guild))```

Comment: You forgot the comma.  `(guild,)`

Comment: @JohnGordon If I do that, I get this error ```'Guild' object attribute 'id' is read-only
  File "C:\Users\Myname\Documents\Bot\Bot.py", line 847, in <module>
    client.run(config["token"])
  File "C:\Users\Myname\Documents\Bot\clearGroup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from Bot import config
  File "C:\Users\Myname\Documents\Bot\Bot.py", line 842, in <module>
    client.load_extension(f'{filename[:-3]}')
AttributeError: 'Guild' object attribute 'id' is read-only```

Comment: At this point I have no idea what your actual code is.  Reading code in comments is too confusing.  If you want help, it's your job to present your full code in a clear manner.

Comment: Oh, ok. Where can I share my code? And do you want every file or just the file that I have been trying to fix?

Comment: Nobody is going to dig through hundreds of lines of code.  You need to make a **short** version of your program that demonstrates the problem, preferably no more than 20-30 lines, and post it directly in the question.

Comment: Heres the main parts of code that are erroring. I added them into this file so its easier to read [here](https://mystb.in/ConsumersArchitectureLogan). I hope this is what you meant. Im sorry if im not understanding you fully.

Comment: @JohnGordon I can add more code to that if it helps you better understand it. But I tried to keep it to the main parts that had the errors.